# Outlook 2016 additional search fields have disappeared

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

My outlook search box looks like this:
[image]

I want it like this again with all the additional fields like Attachments, To, Subject, ...

[image]

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select Search Box, navigate to Refine Tab, click 'More, add the search criteria to the search box.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook, in the grey area at the top, right click, customize, and then in the dialog box that comes up, All icons, select Search and add it

Now in my Outlook I use the Search field at the top of the of the email messages. I click there and that shows the the Search tab with all the search tools including Advanced Find.

I prefer the latter approach and it is all there.

Comment: When I do right click, I only get 'customize ribbon'. It opens a dialog box, but there is no 'all icons' only 'all commands'. Then there is no 'Search' command.

Comment: I mis-spoke when I said "All Icons"  - my error. It is "All Commands"  . Pull that down and there is on my Office 2016 both Search Options and Search Tools. Do you have these command?   Also try the second method above. Click in the Search box on the top of your messages.  That should cause the Search Tools Tab to open at the top of Outlook. Does it open?

Comment: I have Search Tools und Search options in the menu ribbon. But that does not bring back the blue box with the fields like Attachments, To, Subject. I understand that I can use the icons in the ribbon instead. But I would prefer to get the box back. I can't understand why it has disappeared.

Comment: In the newest version of Outlook 2016 (365), the Search Tab is just there when you use it, otherwise it is not there. That appears to part of Microsoft design changes going forward